# how to remove icons in v-expansion-panels (vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to remove icon in the v-expansion-panels.
and here is my codes in Vuejs

```
<v-card-text style="height: 300px;"> 
    <v-card class="mx-auto mt-5" max-width="500" flat>
      <v-row justify="center">
         <v-expansion-panels popout>
           <v-expansion-panel
              v-for="(item,i) in 9"
                :key="i"
                >
               <v-expansion-panel-header>Item</v-expansion-panel-header>
               </v-expansion-panel>
             </v-expansion-panels>
          </v-row>
      </v-card>
  </v-card-text>
```

I tried these to remove icon..

```
.theme--light.v-expansion-panels .v-expansion-panel-header .v-expansion-panel-header__icon .v-icon {
        color: white !important;
    }
    .mdi-chevron-down::before {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .v-expansion-panel-header__icon {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-chevron-down theme--light {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

but none of them works.
how can I remove the icon? please help me..

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels/#usage

Answer (score 4):

Set the `expand-icon` prop of `v-expansion-panel-header` to an empty string

```
<v-expansion-panel-header expand-icon="">Item</v-expansion-panel-header>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/HFkpuGF4ye)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `hide-actions` to the panel-header

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-expansion-panel-header/#props

Answer (score 0):

Just add the props: `disable-icon-rotate`

```html
<v-expansion-panel-header disable-icon-rotate>Item</v-expansion-panel-header>
```